# Cannot run command using cmd in Windows 10

Tags: cmd, windows-7, windows-10, foxit-reader

I have one command line can run using cmd in windows 7 but cannot run in windows 10!(Also run as administrator in windows 10 but still no luck)

I have no idea why this situation will happen.

Below is the command line:

```
C:\Users\user>"C:/Program Files (x86)/Foxit Software/Foxit Reader/Foxit 
Reader/FoxitReader.exe" /t C:/wamp/www/temp/hah.pdf \\wk01\PrinterName
```

Expected output:

can print hah.pdf

Actual output:

I have pause the printer so I can see the print job in the print queue but no print job appear in the print queue(the small window that can see print job) when I run the FoxitReader command line.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: The Windows path separator is `\ `but not `/`...

Comment: actually / or \ also can work

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
C:/wamp/www/temp/hah.pdf
```

with

```
C:\wamp\www\temp\hah.pdf
```

or

```
"C:/wamp/www/temp/hah.pdf"
```

if you prefer to use / (slash).

Comment: still cannot run!

Comment: @user10594468 try set `\\wk01\PrinterName` as your default printer and run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit 
Reader\FoxitReader.exe" /p "C:\wamp\www\temp\hah.pdf"`

try both with and without admin priviledge

Comment: steven, /p work. I think is the \\wk01\PrinterName problem

Comment: @user10594468 Does my command need to be run as admin?


If you consider your problem solved, I'll be glad if you accept my answer.

Comment: steven, the command no need run as admin and i find the solution. Your answer is correct when /p print with default printer but the solution that I have found is /t "PrinterName", which is what I want